# SCALA -- Make groupBy + sum find columns with zeroes

Tags: scala

The title of the question is probably confusing, so hopefully my code example will make more sense.

But basically, if I was grouping-by a set of values, if that value didn't appear in the list, it doesn't get recognized. In the example below, I've been trying to find a way that make the group by recognize that there are three options for names to group by against. But in month "2", Frank does not appear, so he isn't in the group by.

I've looked through the Scala docs, trying to find a way to pass in a list of "group by values", but I'm not sure if it exists.

Any advice on how to deal with this would be appreciated!

Also, FYI, first SO post so sorry if i forgot something. Also also, I'm a Scala noob so some of the code below might be ugly to look at

(Using Scala 2.13.1)

**EXAMPLE CODE:**

```
case class Sale (
  month: String,
  name: String,
  amt: Double
)

val sales: List[Sale] = List(
          Sale("1","Bob",12),
          Sale("1","Bob",15),
          Sale("1","Frank",20),
          Sale("1","Joe",10),
          Sale("2","Bob",5),
          Sale("2","Joe",10)
        )

sales.groupBy(_.month).map { case (month, monthSales) => 
  monthSales.groupBy(_.name).map { case (name, nameSales) =>
    val totalSales = nameSales.map(_.amt).sum
        println(s"$month $name $totalSales")
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2 Bob 5.0
2 Joe 10.0
1 Bob 27.0
1 Joe 10.0
1 Frank 20.0
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
2 Bob 5.0
2 Joe 10.0
2 Frank 0.0
1 Bob 27.0
1 Joe 10.0
1 Frank 20.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you groupBy, you lose context of the full set of names. You need to keep track of all the names and match those names to the sales you actually have if you want to print them. There are many ways to accomplish this. Here's one:

```
case class Sale (month: String, name: String, amt: Double)

val sales: List[Sale] = List(
  Sale("1","Bob",12),
  Sale("1","Bob",15),
  Sale("1","Frank",20),
  Sale("1","Joe",10),
  Sale("2","Bob",5),
  Sale("2","Joe",10)
)

//Note: view is only for performance enhancements. See https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html

val names: Set[String] = sales.view.groupBy(_.name).mapValues(_.head.name).values.toSet

val salesByMonthByName: Map[String, Set[(String, Double)]] = sales
  .groupBy(_.month)
  .mapValues { monthlySales =>
    val salesByPerson = monthlySales
      .groupBy(_.name)
      .mapValues(singlePersonSales => singlePersonSales.view.map(_.amt).sum)
    names.map(name => name -> salesByPerson.getOrElse(name, 0.0))
  }

salesByMonthByName.foreach { case (month, salesByName) =>
    salesByName.foreach { case (name, totalSales) => println(s"$month $name $totalSales") }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd go about it.

```
//quick lookup of sales totals
val salesMap = sales.groupMapReduce(s => (s.month,s.name))(_.amt)(_+_)
                    .withDefaultValue(0.0)

//all months and all names
val (months,names) = sales.foldLeft((Set.empty[String], Set.empty[String])) {
  case ((mons,nams), sale) => (mons+sale.month, nams+sale.name)
}

//make report
for {
  mn <- months
  nm <- names
} println(s"$mn, $nm, ${salesMap((mn,nm))}")
//1, Bob, 27.0
//1, Frank, 20.0
//1, Joe, 10.0
//2, Bob, 5.0
//2, Frank, 0.0
//2, Joe, 10.0
```